# Geo-spatial queries best practice

Tags: database, dataset, geospatial, postgis, modeling

**Context**

I have a big amount of data that is geo located, but the data that i have, has also differents attributes like name description etc..

**Problem**

Given this amout of points, i need to store them in a database (by a geo spatial range?). Also what i need, is to figure out what is the geospatial range that belongs to the point that i want to store, and store it inside. That's true also that, given a geospatial range, i want to discover all my points.

**Question**

How should i set up my software architecture? What sw or db do i need if i want to query a geospatial range and retrieve all the point stored in that range? And how can i store all those point efficiently?
*Is there any standard approach?*

I read something about postGIS, Solr, mongoDB etc.. but i don't know what in this case i need to set up and how to model my problem.

Sorry for the bad question, any suggest to improve the question and it's title is apreciated.

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind for your structure is to choose and optimize the spatial index, regardless of the database you use, without that performance is very bad for large amounts of data, when doing speed tests I recommend that you change the by the data because the spatial indices work like normal indices consulting on data that is cached nearby, reason why time can vary greatly from the actual query time when they are in production

Comment: thanks, for answering, but the question is not related to the "database that i need" but what do i need? a geospatial database with an index in a table? something like that? do i need something like apache solr if i want to compute something? or what?

Comment: for what mensionas, it is advisable to a database with a capacity for doing spatial calculations, recommend postgis as it is very comprehensive and communicates with many applications OSGEO, there are versions for various so, can also be sqlserver if you are using windows, space also has mysql support, but it does also (at least in my experience), if you want to try postgis can find many tutorials about it, here's a livecd that has this and other sw so you can test, also have good documentation tutorials and how each one works http://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/overview.html

Comment: How big is big? To some people a terabyte is trivial, to others 1 million rows is big. What kind of queries do you want to be able to run? It is difficult to advise on Postgis vs MongoDB vs .... on what you have stated about your problem.